# Buck-boost converter dropping source voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, converter

I have two solar panels connected in series, and I'm using them to charge a phone. Together they provide about 7 V when I connect their leads to a multimeter or a basic circuit (i.e. Resistors/etc.). To regulate the voltage/current, I connected them to a step-down buck-boost converter.

The problem is that the output voltage of the solar panels drops significantly as soon as I connect them to the converter, from 7 V to about 1.5 V. This does not happen when I use a regular source (i.e. A laboratory voltage source - a machine).

I tried adding a diode/Zener diode to the solar panel to make sure the current is going in only one way, but that didn't work. Additionally, I tried to isolate the solar panels from the converter by connecting it to a voltage follower circuit or any IC, but that didn't work either.

I'm not sure why this voltage drop is occurring or how to prevent it from happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your lab power supply limiting the current to match what your solar panels would provide under your test conditions (i.e. not max rated current on the panel, but what the current is when it's dropping from 7V to 1.5V)? Could be that your solar panels don't provide quite enough current and voltage will sink since load resistance does not change.

Easy way to check is to hook it up to your power supply and slowly reduce the current via the current knob.

If you have a really simple supply and can't control the current, then you're going to have to us a multimeter to check.

EDIT:
OP has provided the follow quick schematic in comments: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QV51.jpg

While in some use-cases, you might want to do this, generally it's better to have some form of regulation and predictable behaviour. Because there is a large variance in the output of a solar panel, it's generally better to store solar energy into some form of a power reserve first (battery, large capacitors, etc.) and then using that to power your load on-demand.

Comment: You are indeed correct - My solar power isn't supplying a lot of current. I didn't think that this would be the problem, but playing around with the current knob, as you suggested, showed that it is. Then again, I'm not really sure what to do about that. How can I make the current larger with nothing external?

Comment: Directly from a solar panel, you can't. A lot of the times, there's an intermediate stage between the panel and load, which is a boost converter into a battery (most of the time li-ion, for USB mobile device chargers). The li-ion can source quite a bit of current (2A+, sometimes 10A+ depending on the cell). This in turn goes into the load (maybe regulated before it goes in as well), and will provide consistent power.

Comment: Read the datasheet on the buck converter and see if you can convert it to a step-up and use it with a single panel. Step-downs usually have comparatively lower efficiency since some of the voltage will be lost to heat.

Comment: What's the current that your solar panels are putting out?  If the panel's are putting out a low enough current that they could directly charge your phone, then you can hook the panels directly to phone to charge.  The resistance of the phone will drop the panel's down to 5 volts and if the panel's current is not too high, then it will charge safely.

Comment: Assuming I have a rechargeable battery (which I'm guessing has to be 5V+), what do you mean by that? If I were to connect the solar panel in series with the battery, and then the battery to the converter, does that work? From "a boost converter into a battery" I'd assume that I've got the wrong line of thinking, though I don't see how I can connect it otherwise.

Comment: Actually you might already be doing panel->converter->battery. Can you draw a quick schematic and update your question with it?

Comment: @PGT Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing. This is what I have (sorry, not in front of a computer): http://i.imgur.com/m8S8Q4j.jpg Im not sure how I'd go about adding a rechargeable battery.

Comment: Ah, I see. If you look at more widespread products out there, it is usually panel->converter->battery(not phone, but separate) as a single device. And then output from this single device into your phone (which has its own battery and charge circuit) via USB, since storing the solar panel energy in a battery allows for more regulated current when demanded, as opposed to leaving it up to time of day or weather. If you really want to go from panel directly to phone (no external battery), maybe reduce to single panel and boost up to 5V. What is the converter you are using?

Comment: @PGT Problem is that the converter requires a minimum of 5V which isn't being provided because of the voltage drop. However, I did think about using a rechargeable battery, though I don't know how I'd connect it (do I connect the negative side to the positive lead of the solar panel, and the positive side to the positive part of the converter? That makes no sense).

Comment: You would have to design a charging circuit. Fortunately, there are cheap options already done out there: (http://www.ebay.com/itm/5pcs-5V-1A-USB-18650-Lithium-Battery-Charging-Board-Charger-Module-Protection-/221533778016?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3394713060). Panel->charging circuit->battery. You can't just connect directly to the battery; it can damage your solar panel. You can take your panel, step down to 5V and input into this charging circuit, then from charging circuit (already has USB), you can plug phone directly in.

Comment: Sorry, correction, micro-USB in previous comment's link is only for input, not output.

Comment: @PGT Since I don't really have time to order one of those, I'll just build my own. I'm just wonder, is this one reliable? http://www.electroschematics.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/solar-charger.jpg By the way, I appreciate your time and dedication to answering my amateur questions.

Comment: I'm not too sure about the numbers for this but it looks like a standard charger circuit. Keep in mind that the LM317 is a linear regulator and not a switching regulator, and will have a lower efficiency (equal to however much voltage you're dropping between input to output). The LM317 also has about a 1.7V drop to operate, so whatever your MAX input is (i.e. 7V), the MAX input to the battery you'll see will be 1.7V lower (i.e. 5.3V). Hope all this information helps you get to your goal soon!

Comment: @PGT Thank you for everything. I hope it will get me to my goal as well, haha.